# Aspiring Sound Designer should start where?

Tags: sound, production

First off, I am new to this website so I will say sorry in advance if I have broken any rule.

Hi, just one simple question for an aspiring sound designer like me.

What things should I start learning? I know this is vague but I've been blindly watching and researching things re- sound design and it will probably speed things up if I start on learning from ground up.

Comment: sound.stackexchange.com is the Sound Design Stack Exchange.

Comment: We appreciate your desire to avoid breaking any rules. On that front, if you haven't already checked out [the help center](http://music.stackexchange.com/help), I recommend reading through that so you know what the rules are. :-) I'm not 100% sure if your question is on-topic here, and there is a whole [stack for sound design](http://sound.stackexchange.com/), as topo mentioned. It's still in beta, which means it's not as fully formed as other stacks (like this), but there are definitely experienced sound designers there.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply kind sir. Will definitely review the help center for my future reference.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some things that have helped me understand sound design:

- Learn a musical instrument.
- Study acoustics.
- Start recording things.
- Listen carefully to all of the audio elements of every movie and TV show you see. Think about what the purpose is behind every sound and effect. Make note of which are the loudest elements and where elements are panned. Decide for each element if you think it was done well or if you could do it better.
- Learn about related audio for video jobs: foley art, recordist, boom operator, etc. Spend some time doing those jobs if possible.
- Find your local 48-hour film project group and get involved and get on a team to make a film.
- Take courses at your local community college and/or save up for some kind of professional training or degree program.
- Try making new audio for existing video. Force yourself to try it on "boring" things like advertisements and soap operas, as well as more interesting things like battle scenes.

Comment: Although I have done and been doing the things you listed or atleast until til 5th point, It seems that a professional training or program will definitely help me understand even the quantum level deep teachings that I need to learn. Thank you!